# How to password protect website hosted on Amazon Web Services (AWS)

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, passwords

I wanted to create a website that would be like a dropbox of sort, which just has files that me and my organization can access. I wanted to password protect the website, just a simple username and password. I have my own domain. I have been looking all over the web to find how to do this(I am a beginner) and found that using httaccess and htpasswd would be used to secure a website similar to what is shown here: http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/password-protection/

But I cannot seem to get it to work. I am using the s3 bucket and putting the httaccess and htpasswd file in the same folder as the index.html file.  Do you know how I would get my site to have a simple password protection(thats not seen in the source code or by typing in the html)? I am not sure if I am finding the directory correctly or not to implement this password protection correctly. Thank you for taking the time to read this and hopefully this makes sense!
Anyone else had this issue?

Comment: S3 does not support `.htaccess` files.  It has excellent access control mechanisms, but it is not intended or designed for direct, end-user access to secure content without additional outboard components to handle the end-user authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon AWS alone won't do it. htaccess and htpasswd are also not the right tools for what you want to do.

Get yourself a cheap hosting account with a company like hostgator or godaddy or namecheap or any other that will host your web page and give you PHP and MySQL.

You cannot accomplish what you want just using javascript/jQuery. Those languages run on the browser, but you want to store your files on a server. Therefore, you need the language that controls the server - that is usually PHP. *(The other popular solution is ASP, which is by Microsoft and runs on costly and complex Microsoft servers -- PHP is free and runs on (free) Linux and is therefore what ALL of the cheap web hosting companies provide. MySQL is the (free) database that is analogous to Microsoft SQL)*

Next, watch a video tutorial on creating a PHP / MySQL login system, such as the ones over at:

[phpAcademy (now called codecourse, apparently)](https://www.codecourse.com/library/lessons/php-authentication-system)

[theNewBoston.com](https://www.thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=11)

You need to learn more about:

- PHP sessions
- Ajax
- jQuery
- MySQL (possibly)

On a basic website, you can stick your files into directories and control who can access those directories by whether or not they are logged in.

You can determine if a visitor is "logged-in" or not by asking for a username/password and setting a [session variable](https://www.thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=11&video=17059). Session variables are just variables that are stored on the server, rather than on a user's own computer *(of course, that wouldn't work since every visitor has his own computer and your files are stored on a central server -- so that is where the security (variables) must reside, right?)*

Anyway, in a weekend of video watching and trial-and-error you can probably get something cobbled together that will do what you want.